# Why are my buttons running off the screen?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to have my two buttons sit in a row, equally spaced, and I want them of equal height and width. But they look like this at the moment.

I'm very new to React Native so please go gently!

[image]

Here's my code for what's returned.

```
return (
      <View style={styles.screen}>
        <View style={styles.horseProfile}>
          <HorseProfile />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.vitalSignsGrid}>
          <LargeVitalSigns />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._alertHandler}>
            <View style={styles.buttonStyling}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>ECG</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._alertHandler}>
            <View style={styles.buttonStyling}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Resp Pattern</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <View>{/* timer and stop button */}</View>
      </View>
    )
```

Here are my styles.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  horsePatientProfile: {
    flex: 1
  },
  vitalSignsGrid: {
    flex: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#14172B'
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    width: '100%',
    flex: 4
  },
  buttonStyling: {
    backgroundColor: '#2B4250',
    borderRadius: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    width: '50%',
    height: '35%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#84C5C6',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
})
```

Can anyone help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the width of your buttons styles.buttonStyling is 50% which is 50% of the parent Component, the parent is the touchableOpacity, since it doesn't have a set width itself it will stretch with the content, in other words the 50% does not mean the same thing, you should give an exact (relative size, I like react-native-size-matter) to the touchable opacity and justifyContent as space between to space evenly

Answer (score 0):

For height, width try using React Native Dimensions [React Native Dimentions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox)

Import it:

```
import {Dimensions} from "react-native";
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

Example using in style:

```
  buttonStyling: {
    backgroundColor: '#2B4250',
    borderRadius: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    width: width/2,
    height: height / 3.5,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
```

or use [Flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox)